# MySQL: Select pages that are not tagged?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, tagging

I have a db with two tables like these below,

**page table**

```
pg_id    title
1        a
2        b
3        c
4        d
```

**tagged table**

```
tagged_id   pg_id
1           1
2           4
```

I want to select the pages which are tagged, I tried with this query below but doesn't work,

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages
LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )
WHERE root_pages.pg_id !=  root_tagged.pg_id
```

It returns zero - `Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0021 sec)`

But I want it to return

```
pg_id    title
    2        b
    3        c
```

My query must have been wrong?
How can I return the pages which are not tagged correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages
LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON root_tagged.pg_id = root_pages.pg_id
WHERE root_tagged.pg_id IS NULL
```

The `!=` (or `<>`) operator compare two values, but cannot be used for NULL.

- NULL = NULL returns false
- NULL = 0 returns false
- NULL != NULL returns false

You get the point, to check for NULL you should use the IS or IS NOT operator.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If your density to tag to pages is more than 2:1 or so, then using NOT EXISTS will be faster than using LEFT JOIN + IS NULL</s>

```
SELECT *
FROM root_pages
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_tagged
    WHERE root_tagged.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )
```

It is an alternative that more clearly states what you are looking for, a non-existence.

*For the <s>strikeout text</s> above:

The question is MySQL specific, and assuming root_tagged.pg_id is not nullable, LEFT JOIN + IS NULL is implemented using ANTI-JOIN which is the same strategy as NOT EXISTS, except there seems to be some overhead added by NOT EXISTS, so LEFT JOIN is supposed to work faster.*

Comment: I agree it is more clear, but it is often slower (in MySQL, not in general) to use NOT EXISTS. And if you do so, you'd better select a single field or a constant value instead of `*`.

Comment: @Golez - it depends on whether the columns are nullable http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/ but for the question you are probably right. EXISTS is a record-level test, so there is no difference at all with regards to `select *` and `select 'bob'` and `select 1`